# Set State of Color Swatch Buttons Upon Special Condition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, next.js, shopify

On our Shopify/NextJS/React website, products come in different colors. Each color is its own product/URL. All sizes (XS-XXXL) are variants. On the product page, all colors for the product are listed (as color swatches and links to other product pages), and all size variants are listed.

Currently, if a size is sold out, it renders disabled. However; colors only render disabled if ALL sizes are sold out.

My task is to have the color render disabled if the user selected size is sold out in that color.

I have created a function that hits the Shopify API and returns all of the products in the collection, all of the variants, and if the variant is available in the user selected size.

The function looks like so:
`
const loopVariants = () => {

```
        for (let i = 0; i < productCollection.length; i++){             
              const edgesArray = productCollection[i].node.variants.edges
              for (let i = 0; i < edgesArray.length; i++){
                    
                    if(edgesArray[i].node.availableForSale === false){
                        console.log(edgesArray[i])
                        console.log(edgesArray[i].node.availableForSale)
                    }
                    if (selectedOptions.Size == edgesArray[i].node.selectedOptions[1].value && edgesArray[i].node.availableForSale === false){
                          console.log("Sorry, the size " + selectedOptions.Size + " is not available in " + edgesArray[i].node.selectedOptions[0].value)                                                 

                          
                    }
               }       
           }
       }
```

`

In summary, the function tells me if the user selected size is sold out in any of the colors in the collection. If the color is sold out in the user selected size, the color should render disabled.

My question is, how can I utilize this function to properly set the state of the color swatch to render disabled?

The color swatch div is as follows:

`<div key={${value}-${index}} style={{ backgroundColor: bgColor }}>`

I understand that the selectedSize button probably needs an onClick function, and the color swatch div needs a condition that, if true, renders it disabled. Or, maybe an onClick function is not necessary, and only a boolean condition can be used on the color swatch div/div styles.

How can I utilize the logic in the function to create a condition, that, if true, renders the color swatch disabled?

For example:

Product: Blue Hat
Product Colors: Blue, Green, Red, Purple
Product Sizes: XS, S, M, L

If I select M, and Blue is sold out in medium, Blue should render disabled because it is only sold out in M.

**what i tried:**

I wrote functional logic for the computer to check the user selected size, and check all products in the collection to see if any products/colors are unavailable in the selected size.

I have not found a way to set the function to a condition, and change the state of the color swatch div that is unavailable in the selected size.